# Beginning Address Endless Loop

Tags: c++, file, iostream, memory-address

I'm trying to get the beginning address of each line of my file as I read it, and print it out to the screen, but for some reason it just results in an endless loop. The file i'm reading is just a normal text file. Here's what I have going right now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv){
    ifstream file;
    string name, lnstr;
    int addy;

    if (argc > 1)
        name = argv[1];
    else
    {
        cout << "Please Enter Your Filename: ";
        getline(cin, name);
    }
    file.open(name.data());
    if(!file)
    {
        perror(name.data());
        exit(1);
    }
    addy = 0;
    while(getline(file, lnstr))
    {
        cout << file.seekg(addy, ios::beg) << endl;
        addy++;
    }
}
```

Even if I put 0 as the first parameter of seekg, it still results in an endless loop, or it just shows the same number a bunch of times. Not sure what i'm missing.

Comment: think of what ios::beg does in your while loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call ios::beg you set the position of the get pointer to the beginning of the file. You don't actually need this call and this code should work for you:

```
file.open(name.c_str()); // open file
if(file) {
  while(getline(file, lnstr)) {
    cout<< lnstr <<endl;
  }
}
```

[More on seekg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/seekg/).

Comment: lnstr is just the text in my file. Do I hvae to covert it to c_str() for this to work?

Comment: In your case, if you declare Instr as a string you do not need to use c_str().

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [`tellg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/tellg/), not `seekg`.

Comment: I don't understand.  Show what as an 8 byte value?

Comment: The Address as an 8byte value

Comment: @Derp The address of what? Files don't have memory addresses unless you memory map them.

Comment: `tellg` should return a 64-bit value on a 64-bit system.  On a 32-bit system with 64-bit files, I'm not sure.  You might need to use `FILE`s instead of `iostream`s so you can use `ftelli64`.

Comment: Or you could just do `addy += name.size() + 1` each time through the loop, and don't use seek/tell at all.